# Weird scope issue in .bat file

Tags: scope, batch-file

I'm writing a simple .bat file and I've run into some weird behavior.  There are a couple places where I have to do a simple if/else, but the code inside the blocks don't seem to be working correctly.

Here's a simple case that demonstrates the error:

```
@echo off

set MODE=FOOBAR

if "%~1"=="" (
  set MODE=all
  echo mode: %MODE%
) else (
  set MODE=%~1
  echo mode: %MODE%
)
echo mode: %MODE%
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
C:\>test.bat test
mode: FOOBAR
mode: test
```

Why is the echo inside the code block not getting the new value of the variable?  In the actual code I'm writing I need to build a few variables and reference them within the scope of the if/else.  I could switch this to use labels and gotos instead of an if/else, but that doesn't seem nearly as clean.

What causes this behavior?  Is there some kind of limit on variables within code blocks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are running into the problem of cmd's static variable expansion. The MODE variable is only evaluated once. You can see this if you omit the @echo off line.

From the set /? documentation:

> Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has
>   been added.  This support is always
>   disabled by default, but may be
>   enabled/disabled via the /V command
>   line switch to CMD.EXE.  See CMD /?
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion is useful for getting around
>   the limitations of the current
>   expansion which happens when a line of
>   text is read, not when it is executed.
>   The following example demonstrates the
>   problem with immediate variable
>   expansion:
>
> ```
>  set VAR=before
>  if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>      set VAR=after
>      if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
>  )
> ```
>
> would never display the message, since
>   the %VAR% in BOTH IF statements is
>   substituted when the first IF
>   statement is read, since it logically
>   includes the body of the IF, which is
>   a compound statement.  So the IF
>   inside the compound statement is
>   really comparing "before" with "after"
>   which will never be equal.  Similarly,
>   the following example will not work as
>   expected:
>
> ```
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=%LIST% %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```
>
> in that it will NOT build up a list of
>   files in the current directory, but
>   instead will just set the LIST
>   variable to the last file found.
>   Again, this is because the %LIST% is
>   expanded just once when the FOR
>   statement is read, and at that time
>   the LIST variable is empty. So the
>   actual FOR loop we are executing is:
>
> ```
> for %i in (*) do set LIST= %i
> ```
>
> which just keeps setting LIST to the
>   last file found.
>
> Delayed environment variable expansion
>   allows you to use a different
>   character (the exclamation mark) to
>   expand environment variables at
>   execution time.  If delayed variable
>   expansion is enabled, the above
>   examples could be written as follows
>   to work as intended:
>
> ```
> set VAR=before
> if "%VAR%" == "before" (
>     set VAR=after
>     if "!VAR!" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
> )
>
> set LIST=
> for %i in (*) do set LIST=!LIST! %i
> echo %LIST%
> ```

Comment: Is there a way to set that flag programatically at the top of a bat file?  Most of the time this will be run either by another bat file, and the environment it's run in isn't fixed (might be double-clicked, might be run from a cygwin shell, might be from cmd, etc).

Comment: @Herms, "setlocal enabledelayedexpansion" at the start, "endlocal" at the end.

Answer (score 2):

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

will enable the /v flag

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to already anwered here.

### Long answer article:

https://rsdn.org/article/winshell/NTCommandProcessor.xml

The google translated variant is pretty broken, but you can at least read the raw text:

https://translate.google.com/?sl=ru&tl=en&text=https%3A%2F%2Frsdn.org%2F%3Farticle%2Fwinshell%2FNTCommandProcessor.xml&op=translate

Start read from `Conditional block` section.

### Short answer:

The block operator `(...)` blocks a %-variable expansion until the top most scope. You have to exit the scope out to be able to use %-variable as is:

```
@echo off

set "MODE="
(
  (
    set MODE=all
    echo MODE=%MODE%
  )
  echo MODE=%MODE%
)
echo MODE=%MODE%
```

Or use `call` prefix to reevaluate it in place:

```
@echo off

set "MODE="
(
  (
    set MODE=all
    call echo MODE=%%MODE%%
  )
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the read and write use different scoping rules.

If you eliminate this line

```
set MODE=FOOBAR
```

it will work as expected. So you'll probably need to have a complex series if if/elses to get the variables populated as you'd like.

Comment: Actually no, it doesn't.  That set at the top wasn't originally there.  If I omit that then the first time I run the bat file the first echo is empty.  The second time I run it (from the same cmd instance) the first echo shows the last used value.

Comment: You're right, I'd run the script a second time.. well spotted!