# Batch file fails to set environment variable within conditional statement

Tags: batch-file

Why does the following Windows Batch File output `Foo` followedby `Bar`, rather than `Baz`?

```
@echo off
setlocal

set _=Foo
echo %_%
set _=Bar
if 1==1 (
    set _=Baz
    echo %_%
)
```

The output on my system (Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]) is:

```
Foo
Bar
```

If I remove the conditional statement, the expected output of `Foo` and `Baz` is observed.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/305605/weird-scope-issue-in-bat-file

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What's happening is that variable substitution is done when a line is read. What you're failing to take into account is the fact that:

```
if 1==1 (
    set _=Baz
    echo %_%
)
```

is *one* "line", despite what you may think. The expansion of `"%_%"` is done *before* the `set` statement.

What you need is delayed expansion. Just about every single one of my command scripts starts with `"setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion"` so as to use the full power of `cmd.exe`.

So my version of the script would be:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set _=Foo
echo !_!
set _=Bar
if 1==1 (
    set _=Baz
    echo !_!
)

endlocal
```

This generates the correct `"Foo", "Baz"` rather than `"Foo", "Bar"`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the detailed explanation. I think I'm coming up against this exact limitation once again, but in a more restricted environment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/879023/honoring-exit-codes-from-batch-files-invoked-by-msbuild Unfortunately I don't have the ability to turn on command extensions if I'm using the MSBuild `Exec` task... hmmm...

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this is the same as the answer to:[Weird scope issue in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305605/weird-scope-issue-in-bat-file). See there for more details. Basically variable expansion is done at line read time, not at execution time.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
@echo off
setlocal

set _=Foo
echo %_%
set _=Bar
if "1" NEQ "2" goto end
set _=Baz
echo %_%
:end
```