# Honoring exit codes from batch files invoked by msbuild

Tags: msbuild, batch-file, msbuild-task

I have a batch file that is using the `exit` command to return an exit code.

This batch file may, in some cases, be invoked interactively from a commandline, or in other cases, may be run as part of an MSBuild project, using the `Exec` task.

- If I use `exit %errorlevel%` within my batch file this works well and MSBuild sees the error code, **however** an interactive user who is running the batch file from a command window will get a rude exit of cmd.exe in this case.
- If I use `exit /b %errorlevel%` the interactive scenario does not get a rude exit, but this also means that the `cmd` launched by my `Exec` task also does not exit, and therefore MSBuild does not see the return value.

As a solution to both problems, I am trying to use `exit /b` but launch the batch file from my build script like this:

```
<Exec Command="Batch.cmd params &amp; exit %errorlevel%" />
```

The idea being that I explicitly take the 'non-terminal' return from `exit /b` and manually call `exit` to propogate this value outside of `cmd.exe` where the `Exec` Build Task can see it.

This seems like the perfect solution, however it isn't working. `Exec` still doesn't get the correct error value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way to handle this could be to have MSBuild pass a parameter to the batch file so that it knows that MSBuild is calling it instead of from a command prompt.
For example I have created the sample file test.bat shown below

```
ECHO OFF

IF (%1)==() goto Start
SET fromMSBuild=1

:Start

ECHO fromMSBuild:%fromMSBuild%


REM ***** Perform your actions here *****

set theExitCode=101
GOTO End



:End
IF %fromMSBuild%==1 exit %theExitCode%


REM **** Not from MSBuild ****

ECHO Exiting with exit code %theExitCode%
exit /b %theExitCode%
```

And I've created the MSBuild file wrapper.proj which is:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Demo" ToolsVersion="3.5"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BatchFile>test.bat</BatchFile>
    <FromMSBuild>FromMSBuild</FromMSBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="Demo">

    <Message Text="Executing batch file $(BatchFile)" Importance="high"/>

    <PropertyGroup>
      <_Command>$(BatchFile) $(FromMSBuild)</_Command>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(_Command)">
      <Output PropertyName="CommandExitCode" TaskParameter="ExitCode"/>
    </Exec>

    <Message Text="CommandExitCode: $(CommandExitCode)"/>
    
  </Target>
</Project>
```

If you execute the file test.bat from the command prompt the result is

```
C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile>test.bat

C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile>ECHO OFF
fromMSBuild:0
Exiting with exit code 101
```

And from MSBuild the result is:

```
C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile>msbuild Wrapper.proj /t:Demo /fl /nologo
Build started 5/18/2009 10:54:52 PM.
Project "C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile\Wrapper.proj" on node 0 (Demo target(s)).
  Executing batch file test.bat
  fromMSBuild:1
C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile\Wrapper.proj(17,5): error MSB3073: The command "test.bat FromMSBuild" exi
ted with code 101.
Done Building Project "C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile\Wrapper.proj" (Demo target(s)) -- FAILED.


Build FAILED.

"C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile\Wrapper.proj" (Demo target) (1) ->
(Demo target) ->
  C:\Data\Development\My Code\Community\MSBuild\BatchFile\Wrapper.proj(17,5): error MSB3073: The command "test.bat FromMSBuild" e
xited with code 101.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is a bit older, but the response may still be of interest, so here goes:

Slightly modify your MSBuild task to

```
<Exec Command='cmd.exe /C "call Batch.cmd params &amp;&amp; exit %errorlevel%"' />
```

And keep the

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

in your Batch.cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but what if you just set an environment variable named ERRORLEVEL? Hidden after the content of your Exec command, MSBuild has "exit %ERRORLEVEL%". %ERRORLEVEL% if set overrides any actual error level.