# Regex to identify DOS environment variables within braces

Tags: regex, batch-file

The following DOS script snippet has a bug:

```
if not exist %MyFolder% (
    mkdir %MyFolder%
    if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 (
        rem WARNING: the line above has a bug! 
        rem %errorlevel% will be the errorlevel 
        rem of the if statement because of the (parentheses)
        echo Error: Could not create folder %MyFolder%
        goto AnErrorOccurred
    )
)
```

The fix is to use `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` as follows:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not exist %MyFolder% (
    mkdir %MyFolder%
    if !errorlevel! GEQ 1 (
        rem WARNING: the line above has a bug! 
        rem !errorlevel! will be the errorlevel 
        rem of the if statement because of the (parentheses)
        echo Error: Could not create folder %MyFolder%
        endlocal & goto AnErrorOccurred
    )
)
endlocal
```

A full explanation of why is available here: [Batch file fails to set environment variable within conditional statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877232/batch-file-fails-to-set-environment-variable-within-conditional-statement)

I want to audit my code to find instances of this bug, I figure a Regex would be an appropriate match, but haven't managed to get one working...

I think the ingredients should be:
Match an environment variable surrounded with %percentsigns%
That is inside (parentheses)

Any suggestions?

Comment: why bother with such things? use vbscript. it comes with your system.

Comment: Do you mean parentheses?

Comment: Yes, JP, I do mean parentheses, thank you

Comment: Indeed ghostdog74 vbscript can be a compelling option for tasks where a dos batch script is also a viable option.

I am not asking the question however in order to decide what technology to use, I have an issue I'd like to manage with a legacy codebase and am looking for a more efficient approach to tackling it than reading every line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**grepWin**

I would use [grepWin](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/grepWin). Depending on the number of instances you have to find, you could write a regex that will give you *all* of them, plus some false positives.

**Example: bug.bat**

```
if not exist %MyVar% echo Hi!

if not exist %MyFolder% (
    mkdir %MyFolder%
    if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 (
        rem WARNING: the line above has a bug!
        rem %errorlevel% will be the errorlevel
        rem of the if statement because of the brackets
        echo Error: Could not create folder %MyFolder%
        goto AnErrorOccurred
    )
)
```

Then use a regular expression to match all lines that start with `if` and have an open parenthesis:

```
$ grep "^[ \t]*if.*(" bug.bat
if not exist %MyFolder% (
    if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 (
```

grepWin will show you all the files that match.

**Percent Symbols**

By request:

```
grep "^[ \t]*if.*%.*%.*(" bug.bat
```

Comment: +1 Because I like the answer, I'll hold out a little while before accepting in case someone can cook up one that detects the %percentsigns% too.

Comment: BTW, the last parenthesis needs a backslash to escape it, instead of "^[ \t]*if.*(" it needs "^[ \t]*if.*\("

Comment: When I escape the last parenthesis, I see the following error: "grep: Unmatched ( or \\(". The escape might be required for grepWin. Not for Unix grep, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't solve it with Regex, because you can't count the parenthesis with a regular language. For example:

```
Stuff (
More Stuff (
Less Stuff )
A %var%
Less Stuff )
```

There is no `(` between the last `)` and the variable. Since I can't count how many `( appear before to know if there's one open, I can't do this with regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, he is using ! rather than % even in the rootlevel of the batch.
So basically you should be able to alternate every % to an ! for your environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

One other way is to use the AND (&&) and OR (||) tests for success (errorlevel 0) or error (errorlevel > 0), as in:

```
if not exist %MyFolder% mkdir %MyFolder%|| (
        echo Error: Could not create folder %MyFolder%
        goto AnErrorOccurred
)
```

I hope this can help.

And by the way, you do not fail to ***set*** the variable, you fail to ***read*** it back.

What happen is, within parenthesis, using %%'s give you the states which was before you entered the said parenthesis.  The only thing I knows work well is the math **"set /a toto+=1"** which will correctly increment the variable.  Otherwise you have two options:

Either use a called function to set the variable or use the **setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION** statement, as previously stated, and use !!'s within the parenthesis.