# VS Post build event declare var in bat file and use it later

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, batch-file, msbuild, post-build-event

I'm trying to auto sign project with certificate using signtool.exe in Visual Studio 2010. Here is my simplified post-build script:

> if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug (
>    call "$(VS100COMNTOOLS)VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat"
>    call "$(WindowsSdkDir)bin/signtool.exe" sign /f "$(ProjectDir)my.pfx" /p mypass /t timstamp.dll "$(TargetPath)"
>   )

`Debug` is for testing purposes. I'm trying to mimic `Visual Studio command prompt` - execute `$(VS100COMNTOOLS)VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat` which adds some extra variables and then use it later. `$(WindowsSdkDir)`is what I need.

While that script works perfectly in simple `bat` file it refuses to work in Visual Studio. Output is:

> call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat"
>    call "bin/signtool.exe" sign ...

Notice that it doesn't recognize $(WindowsSdkDir), which is created in VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat.

Is it possible to declare var in bat and use it later in post-build or I should use another approach?

Comment: Interesting, in my case $(WindowsSdkDir) is already defined--no need to call VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit tricky:

- first, for cmd variables you need to use `%var%` syntax instead of msbuild-like `$(var)`
- next, SET statements from `call` batches do apply.. but `if` body precalculates its variables, so you need several `if` lines instead of just one `if` body. Here is good explanation of such behavior and other ways to avoid it [Weird scope issue in .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305605/weird-scope-issue-in-bat-file)

So, this one should work:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug call "%VS100COMNTOOLS%VCVarsQueryRegistry.bat"
if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug call "%WindowsSdkDir%bin\signtool.exe" sign /f "$(ProjectDir)my.pfx" /p mypass /t timstamp.dll "$(TargetPath)"
```

Comment: It works perfectly. But very tricky indeed. There is some issue with `if` statements and calculated variables.