# Assigning Variable in a loop (batch file)

Tags: batch-file

I'll boil my overall problem down to a very simple question. How do I assign a variable within a for loop within a batch file?

If I use the following batch file in windows:

```
for %%f in (.\Update\!dos\*.zip) do (
    echo %%f
    set FileName3=%%f
    echo %FileName3%
    pause
)
```

It will `echo` the proper value for `%%f` but it `echo`es nothing for `%FileName3%`

I then tested it by directly assigning `FileName3` a direct value like `test`, which failed.

In searching for solutions, a common pointer is to use is `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion`

However, if I add that to the top of my batch file, it simply stops running. So while I think this is likely part of the solution, without the ability to run the batch file to test, I can't determine.

To be clear, with `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion` at the top of my batch file, if I double click the file nothing happens. If I run it from a command line, it just goes back to the prompt as though nothing happened.

So my question is, how can I assign a variable within a loop in a batch file? If the answer is to use `SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion`, then why is adding that to my batch file causing it to do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [windows batch files: setting variable in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5615206/windows-batch-files-setting-variable-in-for-loop)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Weird scope issue in .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305605/weird-scope-issue-in-bat-file)

Comment: Lacking an actual [mcve] it's impossible to say what's wrong with your batch file. There's no reason that the `setlocal` command would terminate your batch file. However, you _do_ need to make sure you use the variables correctly, i.e. use `!` instead of `%` to delimit variables that you want to participate in delayed expansion. See proposed duplicates, and many others, for all the information you should need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, enabling delayed expansion at the top of your script will not work. The reason for that is that part of your source location includes the `!` character, which due to delayed expansion will be omitted from the name, and your script will end because the path `.\Update\dos\` does not exist.

The trick is to only enable delayed expansion, where you need it.

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If Not Exist "Update\!dos\*.zip" GoTo :EOF
For %%G In ("Update\!dos\*.zip") Do (
    Echo %%G
    Set "FileName3=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo !FileName3!
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```

What you need to be aware of however, is that any of your variables which are defined during the loops `SetLocal` will become undefined at the next `EndLocal`. This means if you need those variables later in the code, you'll need to use a method of passing those over the `EndLocal` barrier. *That however is out of the scope of your specific code example, so has not been included in this example.*

Comment: thank you *very* much for your explanation.